# Problem with R rendering base Graphics in CentOS 4

Tags: r, x11, centos

Hi we're trying to get R with the standard gui loaded onto CentOS 4, and under certain users R will not render certain graphics.  When logged in as root the graphics render, but under the restricted user they don't.  The graphics don't render with the error:

```
> testdata <- rbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(3,4,5,4,6,2),c(3,6,7,2,2,1),c(5,4,9,8,9,1))
> pairs(testdata)
Error in text.default(x, y, txt, cex = cex, font = font) : 
 X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 1 at size 16 could not be loaded
```

Anyone come across this one or have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like something is wrong with your system setup -- I don't expect this to be an R issue.

Comment: That's what we're thinking. However, we've googled it, and solutions we've seen have been reconfiguring the font manager, which we've done. Any suggestions on what info would be more helpful to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I only run Debian and Ubuntu so not sure -- there distro-specific sections in the 'R Installation / Admin' manual, and you could try the r-sig-fedora list.

Comment: Cool.  I will try the list Dirk.

Answer (score 2):

I had just about the exact same thing with ubuntu 12.04 and R 2.14.1
I installed the ubuntu packages

xfonts-100dpi

xfonts-75dpi

Instant fix.

Answer (score 0):

You should try "xset fp rehash" to tell X to rescan and rehash installed fonts. (worked for me)